# 2x2 rotation matrix (45 degrees)

Tags: matlab

How do i create a 2x2 rotation matrix that rotates by 45 degrees ?
i researched but all i found is what i used in my code, which gives 3x3 matrix!

```
clear;
clc;
y=@(t) sqrt(t).*cos(4.*t);
num_of_samples = 20 ;
figure;
fplot(y, [0,2*pi])
hold on

tSample = linspace (0, 2*pi, num_of_samples); 
ySample = zeros(1,num_of_samples);

for i=1:num_of_samples 
  temp = tSample(i);
  temp_2 = sqrt(temp);
  ySample(i) = temp_2*cos(4*temp);
end


mXY=([tSample;ySample]);
fplot(y,[0,2*pi]);
hold on;
    plot(mXY(1,:),mXY(2,:),'Xk');
    hold on;
    plot(mXY(1:10:end),mXY(2:10:end),'Xr');


%rotation matrix 
R=rotx(45);

mXYrot=mXY.*R;
```

Comment: Really? `R2d = @(deg)[cosd(deg) -sind(deg);sind(deg) cosd(deg)];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D rotation is essentially the same as a rotation in 3D space around the z axis. So you can simply use `rotz` to create a 3x3 matrix, but use only left upper 2x2 sub matrix of it:

```
R = rotz(45);
R = R(1:2,1:2);
```

or manually:

```
a=1/2*sqrt(2);
R=[ a -a; a  a ];
```

---

Note: If you don't have the necessary toolbox for `rotz`, writing down a 2D rotation matrix on your own for an arbitrary angle `alpha` [is pretty simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) too:

```
R=[cosd(alpha) -sind(alpha); ... 
   sind(alpha)  cosd(alpha)];
```

Comment: FYI, `rotz` is a function the Phased Array System toolbox, a specialized toolbox that few have (even if the OP appears to).

Comment: @horchler: Thank you, I didn't pay attention to that, the OP is probably a student.